# equality check for Strings in System.out.println

Tags: java

I was checking the `==` operator directly in `System.out.println` for comparing string references.My doubt is as per 'String Constant Pool' both strings will refer to the same instance in pool and the output is 'true' then why first output is 'false'.

Below is a sample code:

```
String s1 = "abc";         
String s2 = "abc";  
System.out.println("s1==s2 is:"+ s1==s2);  
System.out.println("s1==s2 with brackets is:"+ (s1==s2));
```

Output is:

```
false
s1==s2 with brackets is:true
```

Answer (score 8):

`System.out.println("s1==s2 is:"+ s1==s2);` compares `"s1==s2 is:"+ s1` to `s2`, and therefore returns false. `(s1==s2)` is true since both get the instance they refer to from the String pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) the `+` gets higher precedency then `==` so first the string `"s1==s2 is:"+ s1` will be concatenated then it will be compared to `s2` which is false for first case because the first string formed by concatenation would be produced in heap.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("s1==s2 is:"+ s1==s2);  -> it concatenates the "s1==s2 is:"+ s1 and checks for equality because of that you are getting false.

Answer (score 0):

you compare `"s1==s2 is:" + "abc"` with `abc` in the first case --> `false`